# QGIS Merge two DEMs of different resolution

Tags: qgis, raster, dem, merge, bathymetry

In QGIS I am trying to merge 2 DEMs of different resolutions where there is a slight overlap between the two i.e. merging a bathymetry DEM with a topo DEM across a shoreline. As it is of a higher resolution and therefore more accurate, I would like the topo DEM to dominate with its zero elevation defining the coastline. The bathymetry with less accuracy to then blend into this zero definition.

Comment: So... what have you tried? Which tools did you use? Where are you stuck? What research did you do on your usecase?

Comment: I've tried SAGA Mosaic raster layers, r.blend.combine, r,patch, merge and Warp, where possible using bi-linear resampling. They all stitch the 2 data sets together but I cannot get the topo DEM to dominate the shoreline position. The topo DEM is at 1m resolution and the bathymetry at 50m. I'm setting the combined layer to 10m.

Comment: I would get the XYZ value files from each raster and concatenate both into a singular file, then turn it into a raster with a gridding algorithm.

Comment: Hi Gery, I would appreciate if you could elaborate on this. I assume I would need to bring each raster set to the same resolution and then export each as a xyz file. This data would be to large for excel to handle, what application would concatenate this data and how do I turn it back into a raster with a gridding algorithm?